# Eigen vectors sign in successive power iterations

Tags: c++, math, svd, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I have to determine the eigen values and eigen vectors of a symmetric matrix. I am using power iteration method with hotelling deflation.

Consider the test case:

A =

```
    66    78    90
    78    93   108
    90   108   126
```

For this, the dominant eigen vector is [0.4797 0.5724 0.6651]. And my code gives the same output. However, after applying hotelling deflation, the second dominant eigen vector that I get is [0.7766 0.0756 -0.6253]. However, MATLAB says it must be [-0.7766 -0.0756 0.6253]. The third eigen vector is incorrect as the second had the wrong sign. My question is: How do we determine the direction of eigen vector (i.e it sign) after applying power iteration?

```
void eig(vector <vector<double> > A, vector <vector <double> > &eigen_vectors, vector <double> &eigen_values){
        int n = data.size();
        for(int loop=0;loop<n;loop++){
            double c[n]; //Will store A*x
            vector <double> x(n); //Will store the current eigen vector
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                x[i] = 1;
            }
            double y,k=0;
            do{
                y=k;
                k = 0;          
                for(int i=0;i<n;i++){   
                    c[i]=0;
                    for (int j=0;j<n;j++){
                        c[i]+=A[i][j]*x[j];
                    }
                    k += c[i]*c[i];
                }
                k = sqrt(k);
                for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                    x[i]=c[i]/k;
            }while (fabs(k-y)>0.000001);

           /* The eigen value has been determined. 
              Now we have to determine the sign of eigen value. 
             To do this I am calculating A*v and comparing the sign with lambda*v */
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){   
                c[i]=0;
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                    c[i]+=A[i][j]*x[j];
                }
            }
            //Determine the sign of k
            if((x[0]<0 && c[0]>0) || (x[0]>0 && c[0]<0)){
                k = -k;
            }


            eigen_values.push_back(k);
            eigen_vectors.push_back(x);
            double v[n][n];
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                    v[i][j] = x[i]*x[j];
                }
            }
            // Apply hotelling deflation
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
                   A[i][j] = A[i][j] - k*v[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Eigenvectors can be arbitrartily scaled by any constant. Since both side in Ax = lambda x will be scaled by the same amount, the equation is still true. Since the vector is being normalized, you see this as the sign changing.

Comment: "Eigenvectors can be arbitrarily scaled by any constant. " I agree to this. But the sign does matter, right? When should I change the sign? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: -1 and 1 are both constants. Do you need to change the sign for a particular reason? If v is an eigenvector, -v is an equally `good` eigenvector.

Comment: if you really want, maybe you could enforce that the first element of every eigenvector is positive? Ie multiply all vectors with negative virst elements by -1

Comment: So, are you saying that the answer that I am getting is correct? The third eigen vector that I am getting is [0.352414 0.768886 0.533497]. This doesn't satisfy Ax=lambda x. What about this? Is there something I am missing or is it because of some bug in the code?

Comment: @evamicur Thank you very much. All my questions are resolved now. I did some research only to find that the error was in my own understanding of fundamentals. You were correct. There is nothing wrong with the code. The sign of eigen vector doesn't matter and doesn't effect hotelling deflation. And most importantly, hotelling deflation only works for symmetric AND normal matrices. I calculated the SVD and the left and right vectors matched as expected.

Comment: Consider the linear transformation ((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0)) which is an orthogonal projection in the xy plane. It has precisely two eigenspaces: the z axis (x = y = 0) is a one-dimensional eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue 0; (0, 0, 1) and (0, 0, -1) are the only normalized eigenvectors in this eigenspace. The xy plane (z = 0) is the second eigenspace, and this is two-dimensional and corresponds to the eigenvalue 1. Any non-zero vector of the form (a, b, 0) where a and b are any real numbers (not both equal to zero) is an eigenvector in this eigenspace. To be continued...

Comment: (cont.) An example of an orthonormal basis in this eigenspace is {(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0)}. A different example is {(1, 1, 0) / sqrt(2), (1, -1, 0) / sqrt(2)}.

Comment: Notice that every real symmetric matrix is normal. As is every real orthogonal matrix.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it (or its answer) is about pure mathematics.